# JQuery error on wordpress page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html code with jquery which is running without any error locally. But when I put that html code in word-press page (Thrive editor) I am getting too many errors. how can I resolve that ?
In html I am using the following version of Jquery and datatables.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
```

The error in the console are the following

1. Uncaught TypeError: $.widget is not a function
2. $.widget is not a function
3. Uncaught TypeError: ThriveGlobal.$j(...).not(...).filter(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function
4. Uncaught TypeError: b(...).not(...).filter(...).mediaelementplayer is not a function

Comment: Also look in the network tab for any 400s/404s etc (missing files)

Comment: My bet is you are including jQuery more than once in page. Make sure to use wordpress queue system to include your scripts

Comment: You need add jquery very first before others scripts added. It will be helpful if you can provide code and error message to solve the issue

Comment: My WP jquery version is older I think. But I am including the latest version in my code (3.3.1). How can I disable the older ? I am not familiar with php.

Answer (score 0):

in wordpress you must change $ by jQuery

jQuery is inculded by adding the following before wp_head

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
```

Comment: by adding <?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>

Comment: sorry i'm newbe here i'dont know how to edit my post